# Attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'y' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm new here and I'm struggling with this error in Corona, when game ends (lives=0) and I try to remove the background (that is moving with a function "move"):

"Attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'y' (a nil value)"
in line "background.y = background.y + 4"

Is there anybody who can explain me what is the mistake?

THE CODE:

```
--add PHYSICS

local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()
physics.setGravity( 0, 0 )

local lives = 1
local died = false


--###


--add background

background = display.newImageRect( "background.png", 800, 14000 )
    background.x = display.contentCenterX
    background.y = 730
    background.myName = "background"


--add bottle

 bottiglia = display.newImageRect( "bottiglia.png", 41, 104 )
    physics.addBody( bottiglia, "dynamic", { radius=45, bounce=0.5 } )
    bottiglia.x = display.contentCenterX
    bottiglia.y =  10
    bottiglia.myName = "bottiglia"


--function move

local function move()
               bottiglia.y = bottiglia.y + 4
               background.y = background.y + 4
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", move )


--###


--add player

studente = display.newImageRect( "studente.png", 98, 79 )
    studente.x = display.contentCenterX
    studente.y = display.contentHeight - 100
    physics.addBody( studente, { radius=40, isSensor=true } )
    studente.myName = "studente"


--###


--function collision

local function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

        local obj1 = event.object1
        local obj2 = event.object2

if ( ( obj1.myName == "studente" and obj2.myName == "bottiglia" ) or
                 ( obj1.myName == "bottiglia" and obj2.myName == "studente" ) )
        then
            if ( died == false ) then
                died = true

-- lives update
                lives = lives - 1
                livesText.text = "Lives: " .. lives
if ( lives == 0 ) then
                    display.remove( studente )
                    display.remove( background)
timer.performWithDelay( 100, endGame )
                end
else
                    studente.alpha = 0
                    timer.performWithDelay( 500, restoreStudente )
                end

end          
end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )



livesText = display.newText( "Lives: " .. lives, 200, 80, native.systemFont, 36 )
```

--thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The Runtime listener (`move` function) is working all the time. It changes position of `bottiglia` and `background` objects but since `background` does not exist any more you get an error.

A simple solution is to remove the global listener using Runtime:[removeEventListener()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/EventDispatcher/removeEventListener.html) before you remove the `background` object.

Use `Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", move)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want remove listener, you can add checks for nil:

```
--function move
local function move()
    if (bottiglia ~= nil and bottiglia.y ~= nil) then 
        bottiglia.y = bottiglia.y + 4
    end

    if (background~= nil and background.y ~= nil) then 
        background.y = background.y + 4
    end
end
```

This is also pretty risky to use such global variables: bottiglia and background.

You can make it little safer if make them as (or something like that):

```
myGlobalsVars = { }
myGlobalsVars.myGlobalsVars = display.newGroup()
myGlobalsVars.background = display.newGroup()
```